# How to Reset DynamoDB Table Write throughput after the table creation using AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to Reset DynamoDB Table Write and read throughput after my build creates the table using AWS Lambda Function. I need to provision 200 RCU and 600 WCU during an intial run to write my data to the table. Once written, my table does not require more than 50 WCU and 20 RCU. I currently reset the value in dynamoDB console once the table is created.

Developers use circle CI which uses the environment variables for provision RCU/WCU and trigger the build that creates the lambda functions and dynamoDB. AS an admin, I don't have access to the code repo but basically, it creates required tables via Circle CI build triggers using the source code via GitHub Repo. I was asked to automate the problem described above.

We would like to write a new lambda function triggered once successful creation of DyanamoTable during the initial run. This new function should reset the table throughput value to 50WCU and 20 RCU without relying on Dynamo Autoscale. I researched many places, went over AWS documentation, but could not find details or functions that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [UpdateTable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html#DDB-UpdateTable-request-BillingMode) API?

You can have the [ProvisionedThroughput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ProvisionedThroughput.html) object inside your request that update WCU/RCU

Does this answer makes sense to you?

Comment: Yes, I did check that. I was looking to automate it with that API using lambda. Function I created was not working so I might just use circleCI to trigger cli command to update the table! Thanks, gave you +1